# Repeat Event Monthly php mktime

Tags: php, calendar, repeat, mktime

I have a reservation tool that allows for repeating events to be scheduled. I have been able to figure out daily and weekly repeating, but hung up on the monthly repeat because of the varying days in a month.

The goal is to repeat the reservation every third Thursday of the month for example. I thought I had it by using some simple math and scheduling it at interval of 28, but that did not work. I am assuming my code needs some additional variable.

I have a form that passes my numeric value and that worked as I mentioned for daily and weekly repeats. You will see I passed 28 as my value for monthly, but causes issue. It does repeat on the same day, but over time on the wrong week.

```
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="recurring_span" value="1" checked="checked"/><img src='images/icons/calendar-select-days-span.png' alt='daily' title='Daily'>&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="recurring_span" value="7"><img src='images/icons/calendar-select-days.png' alt='weekly' title='Weekly'/>&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="recurring_span" value="28"><img src='images/icons/calendar-select-days.png' alt='montly' title='Monthly'/>
    </p>
```

The processing php is as follows (sorry if I am including too much, but as I said not great with PHP, figured more was better than less):

```
//store recurring reservation
        if ($recurring_date > $reservation_date){
            $repeatid = querySQL('res_repeat');
            $keys[] = 'repeat_id';
            $values[] = "'".$repeatid."'";
        }

        // UNIX time
        $res_dat = mktime(0,0,0,(int)$m1,(int)$d1,(int)$y1);
        $recurring_date = mktime(0,0,0,(int)$m2,(int)$d2,(int)$y2);
        $recurring_date = ($recurring_date<$res_dat) ? $res_dat : $recurring_date;

        // daily or weekly recurring?
        $recurring_span = ($_POST['recurring_span']) ? $_POST['recurring_span'] : 1;

        //cut both " ' " from reservation_pax
        $res_pax = substr($_SESSION['reservation_pax'], 0, -1);
        $res_pax = substr($_SESSION['reservation_pax'], 1);

        // check if pax not '0'; prevent 'Christof Keller' bug
        if ($res_pax < 1) {
            $res_pax = 1;
        }
        //cut both " ' " from reservation_time
        $startvalue = $_SESSION['reservation_time'];
        $startvalue = substr($startvalue, 0, -1);
        $startvalue = substr($startvalue, 1);

        // do not subtract pax and table when reservation is moved
        //$res_pax = ($_SESSION['outletID'] == $_POST['old_outlet_id']) ? $res_pax : $res_pax*2;
        //$res_tbl = ($_SESSION['outletID'] == $_POST['old_outlet_id']) ? 1 : 2;

    // main loop to store all reservations ( one or recurring)  
     while ( $res_dat <= $recurring_date) {

        // build new reservation date
        $index = '';
        $index = array_search('reservation_date',$keys);
        // build for availability calculation
        $_SESSION['selectedDate'] = date('Y-m-d',$res_dat);
        if($index){
            $values[$index] = "'".$_SESSION['selectedDate']."'";
        }else{
            $keys[] = 'reservation_date';
            $values[] = "'".$_SESSION['selectedDate']."'";
        }
        $index = '';
        $index = array_search('reservation_wait',$keys);
        if($index){
            $values[$index] = '1';
        }       

        //Check Availability
        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        // get Pax by timeslot
        $resbyTime = reservationsByTime('pax');
        $tblbyTime = reservationsByTime('tbl');
        // get availability by timeslot
        $occupancy = getAvailability($resbyTime,$general['timeintervall']);
        $tbl_occupancy = getAvailability($tblbyTime,$general['timeintervall']);               

        $val_capacity = $_SESSION['outlet_max_capacity']-$occupancy[$startvalue];
        $tbl_capacity = $_SESSION['outlet_max_tables']-$tbl_occupancy[$startvalue]; 

        if( $res_pax > $val_capacity || $tbl_capacity  < 1 ){
            //prevent double array entry    
            $index = array_search('reservation_wait',$keys);
            if($index>0){
                if ($values[$index] == '0') {
                  // error on edit entry
                  $_SESSION['errors'][] = date($general['dateformat'],strtotime($_SESSION['selectedDate']))." "._wait_list;
                }               
                  $values[$index] = '1'; // = waitlist
            }else{
                  // error on new entry
                  $keys[] = 'reservation_wait';
                  $values[] = '1'; // = waitlist
                  $_SESSION['errors'][] = date($general['dateformat'],strtotime($_SESSION['selectedDate']))." "._wait_list; 
            }
        }
        // END Availability

        // number of database fields
        $max_keys = count($keys);
        // enter into database
        // -----
        $query = "INSERT INTO `$dbTables->reservations` (".implode(',', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(',', $values).") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
        // Build 'on duplicate' query
        for ($i=1; $i <= $max_keys; $i++) {
            if($keys[$i]!=''){
                $query .= $keys[$i]."=".$values[$i].",";
            }else{
                $max_keys++;
            }
        }
        // run sql query 
        //echo "Query: ".$query;                
        $query = substr($query,0,-1);                  
        $result = query($query);
        $new_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $_SESSION['result'] = $result;

        // setup the right ID
        if( isset($new_id) || $new_id != $_POST['reservation_id']){
            $history_id = $new_id;
        }else{
            $history_id = $_POST['reservation_id'];
        }
        // store changes in history
        $result = query("INSERT INTO `$dbTables->res_history` (reservation_id,author) VALUES ('%d','%s')",$history_id,$_POST['reservation_booker_name']);

        // -----
        // increase reservation date one day or week
        $d1 += $recurring_span;
        $res_dat = mktime(0,0,0,$m1,$d1,$y1);

     } // end while: reservation to store
```

I should not I am not so great with PHP and trying to learn, my experience is limited to working with stumbling around existing code. For this project I have been working to customize and modify an opensource scheduling tool for my needs. Researching the mktime without much progress. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is why you should really be using DateTime objects, with DateInterval and DatePeriod - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php - it's so much easier to do these kind of recurrent events

Comment: Thanks Mark...as I mentioned new to php. I read that on another post and tried to stumble through without success, unfortunately at the moment beyond my comprehension to make the transition. my attempts ended up breaking the daily and weekly repeats. Had hoped there was something I was missing using the provided approach that was simple.